# How to ocnvert SPDE to a system of two equations?

Tags: systems-of-equations, stochastic-differential-equations, wave-equation

I need to convert the following stochastic wave equation

$$u_{tt}=u_{xx}+dW,$$

into a system of two equations, the first one is an ODE and the second is an SDE.

> Actually, in the following book [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/book/9780128008829/effective-dynamics-of-stochastic-partial-differential-equations), for the solution of the stochastic damped wave equation
> [image: Stochastic damped wave equation]
> which is wrtitten for its solution that it can be rewritten as
> [image]
> So, my try was that $$du=v dt,$$
> $$dv=u_{xx}dt+dW.$$

Am I right with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are you are dealing with an SPDE, so you can't really convert that to a single SDE (any SPDE is actually infinitely many SDEs).

Many references for this equation are listed in ["Stochastic Equations in Infinite Dimensions".](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/stochastic-equations-in-infinite-dimensions/6218FF6506BE364F82E3CF534FAC2FC5) in 13.21 Wave equations.

See online notes too ["The stochastic wave equation"](https://sma.epfl.ch/%7Erdalang/articles/dalang_slc.pdf) by R.C.Dalang.

For the updated question, indeed by setting $v:=u_{t}$ we get

$$\nu d(u_{t})+u_{t}dt=(u_{xx}+f(u))dt+dW_{t}$$

$$\Rightarrow \nu dv+vdt=(u_{xx}+f(u))dt+dW_{t}$$

$$\Rightarrow dv=\frac{1}{\nu }(-v+u_{xx}+f(u))dt+\frac{1}{\nu }dW_{t}.$$

Comment: Would you mind reviewing the changes I made to the initial question?

Comment: @MathLover I added on more step.

Comment: Thanks for your addition. So, my answer to the main question is right?

Comment: @MathLover not really, you are missing the extra terms they mentioned.

Comment: I just needed to convert the wave equation $$u_{tt}=u_{xx}+dW,$$, not the damped wave equation, so no extra term was needed.